# Client Statistics table (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

Is there any way to clear the Client Statistics table in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (2008 R2) besides create a new query?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Go to the "Query" menu then choose "Reset Client Statistics".

You can customise the toolbar to add this function if you require it frequently.